¿Porque no me carga los estilos CSS en mi JSP?
No entiendo porque no me funciona mis estilos css, nunca he usado jsp, así que no se si así este bien la ruta, ya que cuando entro mediante el controlador de Empleado solo me redirije al jsp ListarEmpleado sin CSS, al igual el JavaScript

Este es el código de ruta del controlador


Hola Jose, bienvenido, para evitar recibir votos negativos, que tu pregunta sea cerrada, y lograr obtener una respuesta, te sugiero que la edites, y agregues el código, como texto.
